# State Push is not a Function

Tags: vuex

i'm trying to add new data to my State and make it available to my View. But i'm getting this kind of error "TypeError: state.Posts.push is not a function"

Somebody know why i can't push new data to my 'Posts' array?

Vue Method look like this:

```
CreateNewPost () {
  const PostData = {
    title: this.title,
    description: this.description,
    image: this.image
  }
  this.$store.dispatch('CreatePost', PostData)
}
```

My Action:

```
commit('CREATE_POST', {
  ...Postdata,
  imgURL: imgURL
})
```

State + Getters + Mutation

```
state: {
  Posts: []
},
getters: {
  Posts: state => state.Posts
},
mutations: {
  CREATE_POST (state, cPost) {
    state.Posts.push(cPost)
  }
}
```